# Spacing is inconsistent between devices with constraints in autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout, interface-builder

The spacing between the blue button and the right edge of the screen are all different widths between iPhone 6 (first), iPhone 6 Plus (second) and the Interface builders representation.

They all line up with different positions on the word Puppies as well as the battery icon...

Open full size to see easier
[image: Open full size to see easier]

Comment: What is your superview? `layoutMargins` are different between devices (16 or 20 points) but you don't snap to margins... https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/layoutMargins

Comment: >What is your superview? - http://i.imgur.com/f98Gl2j.png

Comment: ok, so maybe `button.superview` is snap to `button.superview.superview`'s margin. Hierarchy Viewer may help.

Comment: hmm I just noticed that the word Puppies (from the navigation bar) is not consistent spacing either... I wonder if this is a issue in the simulator...god im struggling with Storyboards and Autolayout...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was just the iphone six plus simulator - Yet to try on real 6 plus hardware...

Thanks for your help

[image]