# View not filling parent correctly

Tags: ios, storyboard, autolayout, interface-builder

I have a single UIView in a view controller where I have set the background to purple.

As simple as that

However its not lining up correctly...

[image]

From the debug view hierarchy with 'show clipped content' enabled it seems that its aligning its self over the left side...which seems to be why it doesn't match up to the edge on the right...

[image: enter idfdsfsd]

This is really just a simple view. Im doing nothing fancy, no constraints  etc. Its driving me crazy.

[image]

**edit:**

Ok.. it turns out that things are fine on iPhone 6 plus and the issue is on the other iPhone device sizes... [See my other questions where I thought that the 6+ was incorrect...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33276148/spacing-is-inconsistent-between-devices-with-constraints-in-autolayout) but it was actually the only one doing the right thing!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug somewhere in my switching of UiView controllers...

I changed

```
 self.currentVC.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
self.addChildViewController(newController)


self.transitionFromViewController(
    self.currentVC!,
    toViewController: newController,
    duration: 0,
    options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn,
    animations: nil,
    completion: { finished in
        self.currentVC.removeFromParentViewController()
        newController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
        self.currentVC = newController
})
```

to

```
  self.currentVC.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
self.addChildViewController(newController)
self.view.addSubview(newController.view)

newController.view.alpha = 0
newController.view.layoutIfNeeded()

UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
    newController.view.alpha = 1
    self.currentVC.view.alpha = 0
    },
    completion: { finished in
        self.currentVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
        self.currentVC.removeFromParentViewController()
        newController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
})
```

And it fixed my issues... Im not advanced enough yet to know what was causing it.